# Django how to get two models in relation?

Tags: python, django, django-models

At my django application users are able to buy specific posted elements. To later-on display a content_preview or the full content of a post i created a "helper_model" ->  Post_Paid_Sell_Tut to check if a user has paid for the post or not. My target is that i can later on display the peview or full content accordingly to the paid or unpaid status but i dont clearly understand how to get those two models in relations at my views.py

i created the following two models for this:

now i want to understand how i can bring those two models in relations at my views.py.
In the end the user will see a form with only a Buy button and some Text. after he hits the button the status should get changed from unpaid to paid for the paying user.

Do i really need a Form at this point?
and if so, how does it have to look like?

Thanks for help in adavance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should change your status choices a little bit.

```
STATUSES = (
(0, 'unpaid'),
(1, 'paid')
)

class Post_Paid_Sell_Tut(models.Model):
    paying_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_sell_tut = models.ForeignKey(Post_Sell_Tut, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    STATUS = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUSES, default=0)
```

This will ease later database searches and will clarify the issues. Then if you are just updating the status then there is no need for any form.

```
def post_sell_tut_buy(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post_Sell_Tut, pk=pk)
    if request.user == post.author:
        messages.error(request, 'You cant buy your own Post!')
        return redirect('post_sell_tut_detail', pk=pk)
    else:
        template = 'Post_Sell_Tut/post_sell_tut_buy.html'
        post.STATUS = 1  # You are updating the STATUS
        post.save() # you are writing the change to database
        context = {
            'post': post
        }
        return render(request, template, context)
```

In addition by passing `post` instance to the template you are desired to view the informations you should follow this:

```
def post_sell_tut_buy(request, pk):
    post = Post_Paid_Sell_Tut.objects.select_related('post_sell_tut').filter(pk=pk)
    if request.user == post.author:
        messages.error(request, 'You cant buy your own Post!')
        return redirect('post_sell_tut_detail', pk=pk)
    else:
        template = 'Post_Sell_Tut/post_sell_tut_buy.html'
        post.STATUS = 1  # You are updating the STATUS
        post.save() # you are writing the change to database
        context = {
            'post': post
        }
        return render(request, template, context)
```

I added `select_related` because when you try to fetch information by the foreign key in from post it will not cause **an extra DB request**.

**UPDATE**

```
def post_sell_tut_buy(request, pk):
    post = Post_Sell_Tut.objects.select_related('author).filter(pk=pk)
    if request.user == post.author:
        messages.error(request, 'You cannot buy POst(s) you created by your own!')
        return redirect('post_sell_tut_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        template = 'Post_Sell_Tut/post_sell_tut_buy.html'
        context = {
            'post': post,
        }
        return render(request, template, context)
```

You cannot access `STATUS` from `Post_Sell_Tut` model. It does not have that field.

```
def post_sell_tut_buy_exec(request, pk):
    post_sell_tut = get_object_or_404(Post_Sell_Tut, pk=pk)
    post_paid_sell_tut = Post_Paid_Sell_Tut.objects.filter(post_sell_tut=post_sell_tut)
    if request.user == post.author:
        messages.error(request, 'You cannot buy Post(s) you created by your own!')
        return redirect('post_sell_tut_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        template = 'Post_Sell_Tut/post_sell_tut_buy.html'
        post_paid_sell_tut.STATUS = 1
        post_paid_sell_tut.save()
        context = {
            'post': post
        }
        return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your help so far but if i use your last block of code i get "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'author' "

Comment: I just updated my question. I need to have the first view to show a overview of the actual item the user buys and the second to trigger the actuall action at the DB

Comment: You should really be sure what will be viewed in the template. If you just will view post_sell_tut model then this is fine but with this mechanism, you will not be able to view other models data except the author.

Comment: Also got on that now ;) i guess i will re-think about this workflow. I also found out that im forced to use a form due to that the user needs to select a currency he want to pay with USD, EUR etc... ...

Comment: I would suggest you re-think in naming too. After a selected amount of time, you will have bad times with names. Also, your mechanism needs improvements in the name of programming. In addition, if this question is done for you please consider of accepting an answer and upvoting it in order to make it easy for others to find and giving credit to the effort.

Answer (score 0):

just create a "Post_Paid_Sell_Tut" object when a user requests to buy a post

```
 def post_sell_tut_buy(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post_Sell_Tut, pk=pk)
    if request.user == post.author:
        messages.error(request, 'You cant buy your own Post!')
        return redirect('post_sell_tut_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        try:
            # throws an exception if not bought yet
            Post_Paid_Sell_Tut.get(paying_user=request.user, post_sell_tut=post) 
            messages.success(request, 'you allready have this post!')
            # ... other stuff

        except Post_Paid_Sell_Tut.DoesNotExist:
            # create Post_Paid_Sell_Tut object indicating that the user bought the post
            ppst = Post_Paid_Sell_Tut(paying_user=request.user,
                                        post_sell_tut=post, status="paid")
            ppst.save()
            messages.success(request, 'post is yours :)!')
            # ... other stuff
```